# How to use PHP if/else Ternary for two sets of possibilities

Tags: php, ternary

I am currently using something like:

```
<?=($d === 'bar' || $d === 'foo') ? 'response' : null ?>
```

To create logic if `$d` is either 'bar' and 'foo', then return '`response`' string. Is there a more elegant way to write this?

Comment: I hope you mean: 'if $d is either 'bar' or 'foo'. Apart from that, it's mainly a matter of preference. I would probably write an actual if for this.

Comment: I might be missing something, but how can as string be both one thing and another?

Comment: You can use `in_array($d, $arr)`, where `$arr` contains your `bar` and `foo`. But @DevDonkey has good note about your question

Comment: sorry - i meant to ask if it is "either" one or the other and not both.

Comment: keep it simple.  keep it readable.   1. get rid of the short tags.  2. youre ternary logic check is fine, so dont over engineer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already written the elegant way. You can use the PHP `in_array()` function, The `in_array()` function searches an array for a specific value.

**Note:** If the search parameter is a string and the type parameter is set to TRUE, the search is case-sensitive.

```
<?=(in_array($d, ['foo', 'bar'])) ? 'response' : null ?>
```

You can make this code even better for readability

```
<?php $foo_bar = ["foo", "bar", "bla", "blaa"]; ?>

<?=(in_array($d, $foo_bar)) ? 'response' : null ?>
```

Comment: this is certainly another way.   But its more expensive in processor cycles and less readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an approach using an array - this makes it more readable on multiple conditions:

```
<?= in_array($d, ['bar', 'foo']) ? 'response' : null ?>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure this is a valid answer since the question is pretty unclear. It says `$d` is supposed to be _"both `foo` and `bar`"_, not _either one_ (which we know is impossible)

Comment: For a big set, readability could be better this way, but for just two options, it doesn't improve it that much, while introducing relatively much overhead of actually creating an array and then checking for a value in it. But it's a matter of preference.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes, that's true. But I would assume that the OP did phrase it wrong, as the given code also tells us that `$d` should be either the one or the other

Comment: @NicoHaase Fair enough

Comment: sorry - i meant to ask if it is "either" one or the other and not both.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes, I'd second that. But the OP just asked for alternatives, and that's one that came to my mind. If you have a better one, post it :)

Comment: I don't. I think OP's one  is best, but this is a good alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

Define your conditions elsewhere and match them with [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and enable strict comparison `===`, if it is required.

```
$response_matches = array('foo','bar');
```

```
<?= in_array($d, $response_matches, true) ? 'response' : '' ?>
```